# Double variables in batch?(Or a way around them?)

Tags: batch-file, variables

I'm making a card game, so I'm trying to set a specific amount of times a number can be used, so I'm basically looking for either a way to do "double variables" or a way around them:

```
@echo off
color 0a
set 1=13
set 2=13
set 3=13
set 4=13
:loop
if %counter%==0
goto :skip

set /a card=%random%*4/32767+1
set %card%=%%card%%-1
goto :loop
:skip
```

....

Comment: You cannot use numbers solely as environmental variable names. Your counter variables is never defined so that will make the `IF` syntax incorrect.  I would advise you to open up a command prompt and type: `if /?` to read the proper syntax for the command.

Comment: You need to access one-digited number environment variables with delayed expansion because `%1%` for example means first argument and a percent sign!

Comment: Your code is not full; contains undefined variables and loops; the three lines starting from `set /a....` will be ignored. if possible provide FULL batch file.

Comment: @double-beep, while that is true you can use variable names as numbers with delayed expansion, that will still cause issues with variables that are assigned exclamation points as a value to the variable when delayed expansion is enabled. Best practice in all my years is just to not do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the logic you are going for.  Your assumption was correct.  You do need double variable expansion.  This can be achieved two ways.  With Delayed Expansion or using the `CALL` command. I chose the latter.  For the example I set the counter to 13 and kept echoing the contents of each of the variables after each loop.

```
@echo off

set _1=13
set _2=13
set _3=13
set _4=13
set "counter=13"
:loop
IF "%counter%"=="0" goto skip
set /a card=%random% %% 4 +1
call set /a _%card%=%%_%card%%% - 1

echo _1=%_1%
echo _2=%_2%
echo _3=%_3%
echo _4=%_4%
set /a counter-=1
goto :loop
:skip
pause
```

EDIT: Now that I look at that again, you actually don't need to use the `CALL` at all or delayed expansion because the `SET` command will take care of it for you.

```
@echo off

set _1=13
set _2=13
set _3=13
set _4=13
set "counter=13"
:loop
IF "%counter%"=="0" goto skip
set /a card=%random% %% 4 +1
set /a _%card%-=1

echo _1=%_1%
echo _2=%_2%
echo _3=%_3%
echo _4=%_4%
set /a counter-=1
goto :loop
:skip
```